# if and elif on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I've been having some trouble debugging this code I've done for homework. It follows the example code perfectly (as far as I can see) but it comes up with syntax error when I answer "Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time" and the "Unexpected EOF while parsing message when I answer GTA V.

```
game = input("What is the best game ever made?: ")

if game == "Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time":
    print ("Top rated")
elif game == "GTA V":
    print ("YES!")
else:
    print ("That doesn't compare to GTA V of Ocarina of Time")
```

Comment: Your indentation  is all over

Answer (score 4):

```
game = input("What is the best game ever made?: ")
```

should be

```
game = raw_input("What is the best game ever made?: ")
```

You probably got the example code from a Python 3 tutorial. In Python 2, `input` was called `raw_input` and `input` was a pretty much useless function that did something else.

Also, if you can, at this point use python 3.

Comment: ... and as for an explanation. In Python 2 `input()` would `eval()` the typed-in string. And `'GTA V'` isn't a complete and valid Python expression.

Comment: Whoops, I actually tried to edit the question to be raw_input, turns out that's the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it's been bugging me for a week.